# Oracle sort not following rule

Tags: oracle, decode

I have the following Order By which I expect to output in ROID order. Instead the output appears in OIDR order. Why would the R be at the end instead of the beginning?

```
select narritive_section as ns, decode(narritive_section,'R','Origin','O','Initial Observation','I','Investigation','D','Disposition') as narritive_section 
    ,person_id, offense_id, entry_date, narritive_text, c_narritive_text  
from t_narritive 
where not narritive_text is null and offense_id =  11514
order by offense_id, decode(
    narritive_section, 'R',1, 'O',2, 'I',3, 'D',4);
```

Comment: You're ordering by `offense_id` first, so that's the main driver of the order. Try `order by decode(narritive_section, 'R',1, 'O',2, 'I',3, 'D',4), offense_id` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have offense_id with higher sort priority then ROID sort. Switching the two parameters in order by should solve your issue.

```sql
select narritive_section as ns, decode(narritive_section,'R','Origin','O','Initial Observation','I','Investigation','D','Disposition') as narritive_section, person_id, offense_id, entry_date, narritive_text, c_narritive_text
from t_narritive
where not narritive_text is null and offense_id = 11514
order by decode(narritive_section, 'R',1, 'O',2, 'I',3, 'D',4), offense_id;
```

Comment: I got rid of the the Decode and replaced it with CASE and added an nrank column to be used for sorting. Worked like a charm.